# How to change cursor from pointer to finger using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is probably really easy, but I've never done it before. How do you change your cursor to the finger (like for clicking on links) instead of the regular pointer?

And how to do this with jQuery since that's what I'm using it for.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

```
$('selector').css('cursor', 'pointer'); // 'default' to revert
```

I know that may be confusing per your original question, but the "finger" cursor is actually called "pointer".

The normal arrow cursor is just "default".

[all possible default pointer looks **DEMO**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor)

Comment: If possible, do this via CSS (say with a :hover selector) and avoid jquery altogether.

Comment: @The Who - Sure, but if changing the cursor is part of a functionality that depends on JS (let's say you have a slider), then you wouldn't want the cursor to change if the user has JS turned off.

Comment: I used this in conjunction with `$('selector').css('cursor', 'auto');` to strip the style when moving the mouse out of the pointer area. CSS classes may be cleaner... with `$('...').addClass('someclass')` and `$('...').removeClass('someclass')`

Comment: when applying this to the body tag and changing to a custom cursor like this: `$('body').css( 'cursor', 'url(openhand.cur) 4 4, move;' );` it doesnt seem to work. I don't know if this is a bug within jquery or chrome. havent tested this on other browsers though.

Answer (score 17):

> Update! New & improved! Find plugin @ [**GitHub**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQuery.cursor)!

---

On another note, while [that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843674/how-to-change-cursor-from-pointer-to-finger-using-jquery#answer-1843690) is simple, I've created a jQuery plug ([**found at this jsFiddle, just copy and past code between comment lines**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/2FZVW/)) that makes changing the cursor on any element as simple as `$("element").cursor("pointer")`.

But that's not all! Act now and you'll get the hand functions `position` & `ishover` for no extra charge!  That's right, 2 very handy cursor functions ... FREE!

They work as simple as seen in the demo:

```
$("h3").cursor("isHover"); // if hovering over an h3 element, will return true, 
    // else false
// also handy as
$("h2, h3").cursor("isHover"); // unless your h3 is inside an h2, this will be 
    // false as it checks to see if cursor is hovered over both elements, not just the last!
//  And to make this deal even sweeter - use the following to get a jQuery object
//       of ALL elements the cursor is currently hovered over on demand!
$.cursor("isHover");
```

Also:

```
$.cursor("position"); // will return the current cursor position as { x: i, y: i }
    // at anytime you call it!
```

Supplies are limited, so Act Now!

Answer (score 9):

> How do you change your cursor to the finger (like for clicking on links) instead of the regular pointer?

This is very simple to achieve using the CSS property `cursor`, no `jQuery` needed.

You can read more about in: [`CSS cursor property`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) and [`cursor - CSS | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

```css
.default {
  cursor: default;
}
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="default" href="#">default</a>

<a class="pointer" href="#">pointer</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very straight forward

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some text" />
<input type="button" value="button" class="button"/>
<button class="button">Another button</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );

  // for old IE browsers
  $('.button').css( 'cursor', 'hand' ); 
});
```

[Check it out on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wisdomabioye/09u9c9mn/)