# Javascript/jquery, get all divs location at (x,y). Forwarding touches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, touch, event-propagation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a list of all elements that resides at the clicked point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735278/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-elements-that-resides-at-the-clicked-point)

I know I can get the element with the highest z-index by using `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`.

The problem is I need to get every div that contains the touch event's location.

**How can I propagate touches to elements underneath?**

I have seen some hacky solutions that show/hide elements while re-generating the event, or pointer-events style with css, however I cannot use these and they may cause flickering...

The following diagram illustrates what I need to do:

[image]

If the purple, green, and blue boxes represent the div elements, and the red dot is the touch location, I need a function that would return "div3, div2, div1".

Comment: I have a [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/2FZVW/) I made a while back that does something similar with the cursor. I'm pretty sure the same principle can be applied to touch variable, however, here at work, i can't even make use of my fiddle, much less see my old un-mined code, I will try to remember this problem when i get home today and get ack up with you. For now, I've included a link to my plugin and perhaps you can find what you need in that "box" so to speak. g'luck!

Comment: It has a function in it which will return all elements under the cursor, tho its been a while since i've used it, so i cant tell you exactly which one off top of my head ([more plugin example use found on this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843674/how-to-change-cursor-from-pointer-to-finger-using-jquery/10353324#10353324))

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about momentarily hiding the elements, as the browser won't redraw until the function ends.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No flickering with this code:

```
$("body").click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX, y = e.pageY;
    var res = [];

    var ele = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    while(ele && ele.tagName != "BODY" && ele.tagName != "HTML"){
        res.push(ele);
        ele.style.display = "none";
        ele = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        res[i].style.display = "";
    }
    console.log(res);
});​
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that the browser wouldn't redraw.. thanks for the help :)

Comment: This method doesnt work on elements that dont already have display=block. This breaks the layout.

Comment: Yes but I can reset the styles accordingly if I have other display types.  Luckily the elements I need this for use block.

Comment: This should also work using `.style.visibility = "hidden"/"visible"`

Comment: hah this is what you meant earlier in chat about being able to drill down and get others. Thanks man it helped out.

Comment: Total awesome sauce!

Answer (score 2):

What about doing:

```
 $(document).click(function(e) { 
    var pageX = e.pageX;
    var pageY = e.pageY;
    $('*').each(function(index) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var left = offset.left;
        var right = offset.right;
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        if(pageX > left && pageX < left + width) {
             if(pageY > top && pageY < top + height) {
                  //Handle the div
             }
        }
    });
});
```