# Link Effect OnMouseOver

Tags: html, css

There is someway of making an img with the link effect onmouseover?

I mean just the link effect (the one that changes the cursor to a finger) not a real link (to somepage or whatsoever)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS to change cursor on mouse over:

```
.class:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
#element_ID:hover { cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
img:hover {
     cursor: hand;
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

This will apply the change to all image tags, to make this more selective just replace "img" with the CSS class of your choice.

Comment: What if he has a image that he does not want the effect on? My bad, just read the ending comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.yourdiv:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

and look here: [How to change cursor from pointer to finger using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843674/how-to-change-cursor-from-pointer-to-finger-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .fake_link {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="fake_link">
    <span>This is my fake link text.</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on applying your styles **inline** (in the html instead of the css) you can do it this way:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;">link text</a>
```

or

```
<img src="myPic.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

By default any href link should display the hand cursor when you move the mouse over it.