# In selenium, how can i track cursor movement on browser with any color?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am performing many task on one page.... i want to know where my cursor is , so is there any way that my cursor location will show in color on browser when i am running the script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several the cursor shape changing techniques using javascript, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843674/how-to-change-cursor-from-pointer-to-finger-using-jquery). You can use it in your code (Java) using

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript
```

the details [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)